# CarouselView in Xamarin.forms is not found

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have tried many solutions for fixing CarouselView not found problem
I tried to add Packages when i add packages a lot of other Issues happend
I tried Also to but controls:CarouselView also appears not found

Comment: Post your code please. And probably remove `controls:` and have a try.

Comment: "a lot of other Issues happend" - how are we supposed to know what this means?  Which packages are you installing?  CarosuelView is a core part of XF.

Comment: It  was more than 100 warning and then the form can not build

Comment: Could you show your xmal and what's your xamarin.forms version ?

Comment: I suggest starting all over, with a new solution, a new project. Add a CarouselView. DON'T make any customizations yet. Build. Does that build without errors? If it is good, then carefully examine that simple XAML, compare to your not-working XAML. Can you find a difference, and fix it? If not, add to your question the not-working `.xaml` file (and the .xaml.cs file that goes with it).